# Managing "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-3.0

I have a powershell script that will move files containing certain "key words" to the corresponding folder listed in various .csv files. While I seem to have the mechanism down to move the files. I keep getting the following error

```
Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\Users\superflysnooka\Documents\Support\Projects\REDTransferAnalysis\REDFileTransferR2.ps1:46 char:38
+         $destinationPath = Join-Path $destinationDirectory $fileName
+                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand
```

I'm not sure if it's because of the way I am passing in required parameters for the main code to execute.

```
$sourceDirectory = "C:\Users\superflysnooka\Documents\Support\Projects\REDTransferAnalysis\staging\"

# Import analog and digital directories from CSV files
$analogDirectories = Import-Csv "C:\Users\superflysnooka\Documents\Support\Projects\REDTransferAnalysis\cfg\analog_folders.csv"
$digitalDirectories = Import-Csv "C:\Users\superflysnooka\Documents\Support\Projects\REDTransferAnalysis\cfg\digital_folders.csv"

# Create log file
$logFile = "C:\Users\superflysnooka\Documents\Support\Projects\REDTransferAnalysis\log\filetransferlog.txt"

# Get current date
$currentDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"

# Loop through files in the source directory
Get-ChildItem $sourceDirectory | ForEach-Object {
    $fileName = $_.Name
    $filePath = $_.FullName

    # Check if file contains "analog" or "digital"
    if ($fileName -like "*Analog*") {
        $destinationDirectories = $analogDirectories.Directory
    } elseif ($fileName -like "*Digital*") {
        $destinationDirectories = $digitalDirectories.Directory
    } else {
        Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value "[$currentDate] Failed to transfer file: $fileName"
        return
    }

    # Move or copy file to destination directories
    foreach ($destinationDirectory in $destinationDirectories) {
        $destinationPath = Join-Path $destinationDirectory $fileName
        if ($fileName -like "*Analog*") {
            Move-Item -Path $filePath -Destination $destinationPath
        } elseif ($fileName -like "*Digital*") {
            Copy-Item -Path $filePath -Destination $destinationPath
        }
        Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value "[$currentDate] Successfully transferred file: $fileName to $destinationDirectory"
    }
}
```

Here is what the first column of one of the .csv files looks like

```
Directory
C:\Users\superflysnooka\Documents\Support\Projects\COBETransferAnalysis\sites\Area1\Analog
C:\Users\superflysnooka\Documents\Support\Projects\COBETransferAnalysis\sites\Area2\Analog
C:\Users\superflysnooka\Documents\Support\Projects\COBETransferAnalysis\sites\Area3\Analog
C:\Users\superflysnooka\Documents\Support\Projects\COBETransferAnalysis\sites\Area4\Analog
```

Comment: Well, that would seem to suggest that at least one of the 2 CSV files doesn't have a `Directory` column, or at least one row with an empty corresponding cell

Comment: I've included what one of the .csv files looks like. It has a single column with the header of "Directory".

Comment: Then it's probably the other one :) You can test it: `Get-ChildItem cfg\analog_folders.csv,cfg\digital_folders.csv |? {Import-Csv $_.FullName |? {$null -eq $_.Directory}}`. Whichever file is returned by that command will contain at least 1 record with an empty Directory value

Comment: You code is very hard to debug because you made into one instruction. with 21 one lines of code and inside these 21 lines of code there is a second for loop.  Why not write the code so you can easily debug.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Super - found the issue thanks to your test inline. It was due to the organism between the chair and the PC. One of the target folder names was missing a character. Huge thanks again for the assist. Have a great one!

Comment: @NanoNet My pleasure ^_^ don't forget to accept your own answer below!

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by the following

- Ensuring the file actually exists
- File name is spelled correctly or else throw an exception.